# While doing multi-objective optimization in c-plex , for different weightages same value of decision variable is getting. Why it is like this?

Tags: python, php, query-optimization, mathematical-optimization, cplex

minimize sum(j in tavail) 0.2*(ptn[j]*1000000-pln[j]*1000000+sum(k in nport)pevch[j][k]-
sum(k in nport)(DOD1[k][j]-dod[k][j])*cap[k][j]*1000)
+0.8*(sum(j in tavail)(-sum(k in nport)(-32768*DOD1[k][j]+49546)*(DOD1[k][j]-dod[k][j])*cap[k][j]*1000);

This is the mentioned  objective function. Here the weight taken is 0.2 and 0.8. With change in weightage values only objective function value is changing. Decision variable is not changing. I have done this by lexicographic method. Is there any other method other than this  for doing multi objective optimization. Whether C-PLEX doesn't support weighted optimization? .

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: That is normal. Different weights **can** lead to the same solution. Notice that **lexicographic** is a very different method (no weights, but an ordering of the objectives).

Answer (score 0):

In order to use lexicographic multi objective you can rely on staticLex as in https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoomultiobjective.mod

```
int nbKids=200;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
float costBus50=625;
     
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
dvar int+ nbBus50;

dvar float cost;
dvar float co2emission;
     
minimize
  staticLex(cost,co2emission);
     
subject to
{
 cost==costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30+nbBus50*costBus50;
 co2emission==nbBus50+nbBus40*1.1+nbBus30*1.2;

  40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30+nbBus50*50>=nbKids;
}

execute DISPLAY_After_SOLVE
{
  writeln("The minimum cost is ",cost);
  writeln("CO2 emission is ",co2emission);
  writeln("We will use ",nbBus40," 40 seats buses ",nbBus30,
  " 30 seats buses and ", nbBus50," buses 50 seats");
}
```

If you want to use weighted sum, change

```
staticLex(cost,co2emission);
```

into

```
10000*cost+co2emission;
```

Comment: This is actually a simple model.But l am working with a scheduling model.This is not working with it. I think ther is no difference by multiplying objective function with weights and by doing optimization using staticlex.

Answer (score 0):

Other methods for multi-objective-
1)Priority - weigh your objectives with an integer value like (1,2,3)-as priority.
2) Goal programming - solve using objectives separately. Then introduce equality constraints using upper and lower deviations for each of the corresponding optima and their objective functions. Then minimize sum of the deviations.
3) Solve all but one objectives individually. Then add constraints (`<=` or `>=` depending upon max/min for each of the optima and objective function. Then solve the final objective.

Comment: Whether all these methods are possible in CPLEX

Comment: The first option, you need to check on cplex manual. Rest are merely modelling- adding constraints & solving as I mentioned. You can Google up & read more.